# An inequality involving Möbius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, summation, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

For any positive integer $n$ show the inequality holds :
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\mu(i)}{i}\right|\le 1$$
I tried induction. when $\mu(n+1)=0$ it is trivial. But what if $\mu(n+1)\ne 0$? I am stuck there. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557998/simple-divisor-summation-inequality-with-moebius-function/558039#558039